# Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:163)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:157)
>       at HttpHeaders.init (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:305)
>       at HttpHeaders.forEach (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:408)
>       at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2210)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:177)
>       at Observable.subscribe (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:165)
>       at subscribeToResult (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/util/subscribeToResult.js:32)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:143)

It happens when I try to upload a file and I don't understand why since I'm not using the length() function anywhere.

This is my html:

```
<app-supervisor-header></app-supervisor-header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <h3>Wijzigen van examen: {{examen.naam}}</h3>
        <form #examUpdateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(examUpdateForm)">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <label for="vak">Naam</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="vak" placeholder="{{examen.naam}}" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <label for="vak">Bestand</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="examen_bestand" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp" (change)="fileChanged($event)">
                <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Hier kun je de huidige examenskelet vervangen.</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="submit" class="pxl-knop float-right" id="zoek-knop" value="Zoek" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

And this the Component:

```
export class SupervisorExamenAanpassenComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() examen: Examen = new Examen(null, '', '', null);
  id: number;

  constructor(private serv: ExamService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  onSubmit(form) {
    this.serv.updateExamById(this.id, this.examen).subscribe();
  }

  fileChanged(e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.examen.file = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params.id);
    this.serv.getExamById(this.id).subscribe((data) => this.examen = data);
  }

}
```

On the second time I try to submit it also tells me the error is from the HTML line 6 which is:

```
<form #examUpdateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(examUpdateForm)">
```

EDIT:

ExamService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExamService {
  examens: Examen[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getExams(): Observable<Examen[]> {
    return this.http.get<Examen[]>(APIURL + '/all');
  }

  getExamById(id): Observable<Examen> {
    return this.http.get<Examen>(APIURL + '/asobject/' + id);
  }

  updateExamById(id, exam: Examen) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    const options = {} as any;
    fd.append('file', exam.file);
    fd.append('name', exam.naam);
    return this.http.put<Examen>(APIURL + '/update/' + id, fd, {headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}});
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the ExamService code?

Comment: Ofcourse, I have added it

Comment: It's being sent to the backend which is in Java Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this parameter from the http.put call in the ExamService:

```
{headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}}
```

You won't need to set Content-Type since, per our discussion below, these will be set correctly for you by angular's HttpClient api.

Also, don't use FileReader to convert the file's Blob content to plain text. Instead just store a reference to the File and on submit append the File and its Name to the FormData. E.g.

```
// Component
private file: File = null;

fileChanged(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0]);
}

onSubmit(form) {
  this.serv.updateExamById(this.id, this.file).subscribe();
}

// Service
updateExamById(id, file: File) {
  const fd = new FormData();   
  fd.append('file', file, file.name);
  return this.http.put<Examen>(APIURL + '/update/' + id, fd);
}
```

Comment: I used HttpHeaders().delete('Content-Type') instead which works but now I get the error `the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found` unfortunately

Comment: Yes you will need a content-type set - did you try 'multipart/form-data'?

Comment: Yes that gives me another error. From what I’ve found I am supposed to delete the content type so that chrome can automatically set it. I believe this happens but somehow it doesn’t see the name parameter of my formData

Comment: Interesting - just had a look and angular's `HttpClient` class actually detects content-type automatically based on the body being an instance of `FormData`. Perhaps try not passing any `HttpHeader` in the options?

Comment: I meant to say, based on the body being `FormData` httpclient removes the content-type for you for exactly the reason you described - chrome is to set them for you. Also (and this is a wild stab ) you could try appending 'name' before 'file' in the FormData?

Comment: If I don't pass any header at all it still gives me the same error. Apparently I've been trying to pass it for no reason then. But yea still the same 'file' error. I also tried switching the orders like you suggested and also that changed nothing

Comment: Ok, I suspect the issue is with the use of FileReader - can you try just appending the file object to the FormData? I think the reason you are getting a no 'multipart boundary error' is because you are passing plain text to the FormData instead of a file (which will be a blob, not plain text). See the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171622/discussion-between-mounds-and-sinan-samet).